# SVN. Access Rights

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu

I can not properly configure access rights.
Once the rule does not seem to work. some directory - as it should be and some not.

I have a repository in two folders - **one**, **two**. 
three users - admin, user, guest.
Rights needed are:

- admin - read and write to the /
- user, guest - read and write only in **one** folder

I wrote in svnserve.conf:

```
 anon-access = none 
 auth-access = write 
 authz-db = /svn.acl
```

Added to the file /etc/apache2/conf.d/svn:

```
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/svn.acl
```

File svn.acl:

```
[/]
admin = rw
* = 

[/one]
user,quest = rw

[/two]
admin = rw
* =
```

in the end **user** still sees the **two** directory !
what could be wrong?

Comment: Can user see what is inside "/two"?

Answer (score 1):

Just as with UNIX directory permissions, users can see *that* a directory they don't have permission to access exists, but they cannot see the contents of that directory. No user should be able to see inside `/two`.

Comment: if change the configuration of auth-access = write to auth-access = none. will change the situation ?

Comment: It will, but not in the way you want. If you do that, no one can do anything with the repository.

Comment: and what to do? I can not understand (

Comment: There is nothing *to* do. As it stands now, the user can see that `two` exists, but can't see inside. That's as much control as you can get with Subversion.

Comment: but in my case the user sees the content /two

Comment: Do they see the *contents of* `/two`, or just that `/two` exists?

Comment: I go into the SVN web under the user, and I can see the contents of the directory /two